# Duplicate row based on value in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of transactions. Each row represents a transaction of two item (think of it like a transaction of 2 event tickets or something). I want to duplicate each row based on the quantity sold.

Here's example code:

```
# dictionary of transactions

d = {
    '1': ['20',  'NYC', '2'],
    '2': ['30',  'NYC', '2'],
    '3': ['5',   'NYC', '2'],
    '4': ['300', 'LA',  '2'],
    '5': ['30',  'LA',  '2'],
    '6': ['100', 'LA',  '2']
}

columns=['Price', 'City', 'Quantity']

# create dataframe and rename columns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data=d, orient='index'
)
df.columns = columns
```

This produces a dataframe that looks like this

```
Price   City    Quantity
20       NYC         2
30       NYC         2
5        NYC         2
300      LA          2
30       LA          2
100      LA          2
```

So in the case above, each row will transform into two duplicate rows. If the 'quantity' column was 3, then that row would transform into three duplicate rows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- where is the code you wrote for this, and what output *did* you get?  You've described the desired output well enough, but there doesn't seem to be a StackOverflow question in this.  Remember that SO is for code *fixing* not code design and writing.

Comment: @Prune I disagree, this seems to fit the description of a specific programming problem. The OP could use some guidance with determining an efficient way to go about solving that problem. Sometimes a person doesn't even know where to begin and an ugly attempt at a solution just clutters the question and wastes everyone's time.

Comment: I appreciate @Prune's advice and I generally agree with it. I think that's a good way to filter out purely lazy questions. This problem though does have me stumped and I haven't been able to provide a meaningful starting place for a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I recreated your data using integers instead of text.  I also varied the quantity so that one can more easily understand the problem.

```
d = {1: [20, 'NYC', 1], 2: [30, 'NYC', 2], 3: [5, 'SF', 3],      
     4: [300, 'LA', 1], 5: [30, 'LA', 2],  6: [100, 'SF', 3]}

columns=['Price', 'City', 'Quantity'] 
# create dataframe and rename columns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index').sort_index()
df.columns = columns

>>> df
   Price City  Quantity
1     20  NYC         1
2     30  NYC         2
3      5   SF         3
4    300   LA         1
5     30   LA         2
6    100   SF         3
```

I created a new DataFrame by using a nested list comprehension structure.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([df.ix[idx] 
                       for idx in df.index 
                       for _ in range(df.ix[idx]['Quantity'])]).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df_new
    Price City  Quantity
0      20  NYC         1
1      30  NYC         2
2      30  NYC         2
3       5   SF         3
4       5   SF         3
5       5   SF         3
6     300   LA         1
7      30   LA         2
8      30   LA         2
9     100   SF         3
10    100   SF         3
11    100   SF         3
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try it on my actual data, I get a "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>" related to the second for loop "for _ in range(df.ix[idx]['Quantity'])".

Comment: Try this: `for _ in range(int(df.ix[idx]['Quantity']))` You can also explicitly convert the column to integers: `df['Quantity'] = dfQuantity.astype(int)`

Comment: OK I got it to work. In my dataset, the index was a datetime series which had some missing dates (not sure if that is relevant). When I set the index to just be regular consecutive integers like in our example above, it worked. For your reference, when I run df.Quantity.unique() i get "array([ 2,  4,  3,  1,  6,  5,  7,  8, 10,  9, 14, 12], dtype=int64)". Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes. You should probably start with `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` in that case.

Comment: By the way, you helped me answer my last question on SO. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yea... sorry about that. I had a lot of trouble deciding :(

Comment: That's OK.  Fabio needs the rep more than I do.

Answer (score 53):

Answer by using `repeat`

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Quantity)]
Out[448]: 
  Price City Quantity
1    20  NYC        2
1    20  NYC        2
2    30  NYC        2
2    30  NYC        2
3     5  NYC        2
3     5  NYC        2
4   300   LA        2
4   300   LA        2
5    30   LA        2
5    30   LA        2
6   100   LA        2
6   100   LA        2
```

Comment: No offense intended to other contributors, but I think this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: but it can use some more info, at least [a link to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html).

Comment: I love this answer. <3

Answer (score 4):

How about this approach. I changed your data slightly to call out a sale of 4 tickets.

We use a helper np.ones() array, suitably sized ,and then the key line of code is: `a[np.arange(a.shape[1])[:] > a[:,0,np.newaxis]] = 0`

I was shown this technique here: [numpy - update values using slicing given an array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648667/numpy-update-values-using-slicing-given-an-array-value)

Then its simply a call to `.stack()` and some basic filtering to complete.

```
d = {'1': ['20', 'NYC', '2'], '2': ['30', 'NYC', '2'], '3': ['5', 'NYC', '2'], \
     '4': ['300', 'LA', '2'], '5': ['30', 'LA', '4'],  '6': ['100', 'LA', '2']}

columns=['Price', 'City', 'Quantity']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index')
df.columns = columns
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].astype(int)

# make a ones array 
my_ones = np.ones(shape=(len(df),df['Quantity'].max()))

# turn my_ones into a dataframe same index as df so we can join it to the right hand side. Plenty of other ways to achieve the same outcome. 
df_my_ones = pd.DataFrame(data =my_ones,index = df.index)

df = df.join(df_my_ones)
```

which looks like:

```
  Price City  Quantity  0  1  2  3
1    20  NYC         2  1  1  1  1
3     5  NYC         2  1  1  1  1
2    30  NYC         2  1  1  1  1
5    30   LA         4  1  1  1  1
4   300   LA         2  1  1  1  1
```

now get the Quantity column and the ones into a numpy array

```
a = df.iloc[:,2:].values
```

this is the clever bit

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[1])[:] > a[:,0,np.newaxis]] = 0
```

and re-assign back to df.

```
df.iloc[:,2:] = a
```

and now df looks like following, notice how we have set to zero past the number in Quantity:

```
  Price City  Quantity  0  1  2  3
1    20  NYC         2  1  1  0  0
3     5  NYC         2  1  1  0  0
2    30  NYC         2  1  1  0  0
5    30   LA         4  1  1  1  1
4   300   LA         2  1  1  0  0

df.set_index(['Price','City','Quantity'],inplace=True)
df =  df.stack().to_frame()
df.columns = ['sale_flag']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print df[['Price','City', 'Quantity']][df['sale_flag'] !=0]
print df
```

which produces:

```
Price City  Quantity
0     20  NYC         2
1     20  NYC         2
4      5  NYC         2
5      5  NYC         2
8     30  NYC         2
9     30  NYC         2
12    30   LA         4
13    30   LA         4
14    30   LA         4
15    30   LA         4
16   300   LA         2
17   300   LA         2
```

Comment: Very creative solution! I'll have to examine it more carefully. Check the other response below for a different approach as well. Thanks a lot for your help. It's much appreciated.