# Repeat rows in a pandas DataFrame based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, repeat

I have the following df:

```
code . role    . persons
123 .  Janitor . 3
123 .  Analyst . 2
321 .  Vallet  . 2
321 .  Auditor . 5
```

The first line means that I have 3 persons with the role Janitors.
My problem is that I would need to have one line for each person. My df should look like this:

```
df:

code . role    . persons
123 .  Janitor . 3
123 .  Janitor . 3
123 .  Janitor . 3
123 .  Analyst . 2
123 .  Analyst . 2
321 .  Vallet  . 2
321 .  Vallet  . 2
321 .  Auditor . 5
321 .  Auditor . 5
321 .  Auditor . 5
321 .  Auditor . 5
321 .  Auditor . 5
```

How could I do that using pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Duplicate row based on value in different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792263/duplicate-row-based-on-value-in-different-column)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`reindex`+ `repeat`

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.persons))
Out[951]: 
   code  .     role ..1  persons
0   123  .  Janitor   .        3
0   123  .  Janitor   .        3
0   123  .  Janitor   .        3
1   123  .  Analyst   .        2
1   123  .  Analyst   .        2
2   321  .   Vallet   .        2
2   321  .   Vallet   .        2
3   321  .  Auditor   .        5
3   321  .  Auditor   .        5
3   321  .  Auditor   .        5
3   321  .  Auditor   .        5
3   321  .  Auditor   .        5
```

PS: you can add`.reset_index(drop=True)` to get the new index

Comment: Wonderful, I knew there was a good solution with repeat, but this nailed it.

Comment: Yep, this was nice. Maybe a final reset_index() too?

Comment: @Wen I love learning new stuff!  You would believe, that i didn't no you could reuse index values in reindex.  I have alway used reindex to shuffle or add indexes but never to duplicate has you have done here.  Beautiful.  Nice one. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks Man :-) SO is good place push us learning from each others (I learn it from coldspeed long time ago :-) )

Answer (score 17):

Wen's solution is really nice and intuitive, however it will fail for duplicate rows by throwing `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Here's an alternative which avoids this by calling `repeat` on `df.values`.

```
df

   code     role  persons
0   123  Janitor        3
1   123  Analyst        2
2   321   Vallet        2
3   321  Auditor        5


pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.persons, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

   code     role persons
0   123  Janitor       3
1   123  Janitor       3
2   123  Janitor       3
3   123  Analyst       2
4   123  Analyst       2
5   321   Vallet       2
6   321   Vallet       2
7   321  Auditor       5
8   321  Auditor       5
9   321  Auditor       5
10  321  Auditor       5
11  321  Auditor       5
```

Comment: when it comes to performance, what is it better `.reindex()` or `.values.repeat()`?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf This solution is faster. But Wen's solution requires fewer characters, plus I was nice enough to leave a nice comment under his answer which spurred all the extra upvotes.

Comment: the only problem I saw with your solution is that the `dtypes` are changed to `object` for every column in the dataframe.

Comment: This works when there are duplicate rows as opposed to BENY's solution which throws a `ValueError` (`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`)

Answer (score 4):

Not enough reputation to comment, but building on @cs95's answer and @lmiguelvargasf's comment, one can preserve dtypes with:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values.repeat(df.persons, axis=0),
    columns=df.columns,
).astype(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the Series method [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html#pandas.Series.repeat):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2, 3],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b'],
                   'col3': [20, 30]})

df.apply(lambda x: x.repeat(df['col1']))
# df.apply(pd.Series.repeat, repeats=df['col1'])
```

or the numpy function [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat):

```
df.apply(np.repeat, repeats=df['col1'])
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     2    a    20
0     2    a    20
1     3    b    30
1     3    b    30
1     3    b    30
```