# How to repeat pandas dataframe records based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to duplicate rows of a pandas DataFrame (v.0.23.4, python v.3.7.1) based on an int value in one of the columns. I'm applying code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336704/repeat-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-value) to do that, but I'm running into the following data type casting error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`. Basically, I'm not understanding why this code is attempting to cast to `int32`.

Starting with this,

```py
dummy_dict = {'c1': ['a','b','c'],
              'c2': [0,1,2]}
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_dict)
```

```
    c1  c2  c3
0   a   0   textA
1   b   1   textB
2   c   2   textC
```

I'm doing this

```py
dummy_df_test = dummy_df.reindex(dummy_df.index.repeat(dummy_df['c2']))
```

I want this at the end. However, I'm getting the above error instead.

```
    c1  c2  c3
0   a   0   textA
1   b   1   textB
2   c   2   textC
3   c   2   textC
```

Comment: Try: `dummy_df_test = dummy_df.reindex(dummy_df.index.repeat(dummy_df['c2'].astype("int32")))`

Comment: Note, you should replace the `0` for `1` else it will get removed with `repeat`. But for me this works in `pandas 0.24.2: `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.replace(0, 1).c2))`

Comment: Thanks, @PMende and erfan, those are both helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just a workaround:

```
pd.concat([dummy_df[dummy_df.c2.eq(0)],dummy_df.loc[dummy_df.index.repeat(dummy_df.c2)]])
```

Another fantastic suggestion courtesy @Wen

```
dummy_df.reindex(dummy_df.index.repeat(dummy_df['c2'].clip(lower=1)))
```

---

```
  c1  c2
0  a   0
1  b   1
2  c   2
2  c   2
```

Comment: umm , how about `dummy_df.reindex(dummy_df.index.repeat(dummy_df['c2'].clip(lower=1)))
`

Comment: @WeNYoBen thats fantastic, if you want you can post this as answer. :)

Comment: No worry feel free to include in yours :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer as to why it's happening can be found here:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4384

Specifying the dtype as int32 should solve the problem as highlighted in the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first attempt all rows are duplicated, and in the second attempt just the row with the index 2. Thanks to the [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*2, ignore_index=True)
print(df2)

df3= pd.concat([df, df.iloc[[2]]])
print(df3)
```

---

```
  c1  c2     c3
0  a   0  textA
1  b   1  textB
2  c   2  textC
  c1  c2     c3
0  a   0  textA
1  b   1  textB
2  c   2  textC
3  a   0  textA
4  b   1  textB
5  c   2  textC
  c1  c2     c3
0  a   0  textA
1  b   1  textB
2  c   2  textC
2  c   2  textC
```

If you plan to reset the index at the end

```
df3=df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```