# Groupby in Reverse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with name of variables, the values for each and the `count` (which shows the frequency of that row):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'value':[10, 20, 30], 'count':[1,2,3]})

var  value  count
A    10     1
B    20     2
C    30     3
```

I want to use `count` to get an output like this:

```
var  value
A    10
B    20
B    20
C    30
C    30
C    30
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336704/repeat-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-value

Comment: How the content of this question refers to the title "groupby in reverse"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `index.repeat`:

```
i = df.index.repeat(df['count'])
d = df.loc[i, :'value'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   var  value
0   A     10
1   B     20
2   B     20
3   C     30
4   C     30
5   C     30
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `repeat` with `reindex` for this short one-liner:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
```

Output:

```
  var  value  count
0   A     10      1
1   B     20      2
1   B     20      2
2   C     30      3
2   C     30      3
2   C     30      3
```

Or to eliminate the 'count' column:

```
df[['var','value']].reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
```

OR

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count'])).drop('count', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  var  value
0   A     10
1   B     20
1   B     20
2   C     30
2   C     30
2   C     30
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer so far. It's the only one that doesn't need to know the labels of the other columns.

Comment: `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count'])).iloc[:,:-1].reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'value':[10, 20, 30], 'count':[1,2,3]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df['var'] = df['var'].repeat(df['count'])
new_df['value'] = df['value'].repeat(df['count'])
new_df

    var value
0   A   10
1   B   20
1   B   20
2   C   30
2   C   30
2   C   30
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to achieve this. Here is one cheeky approach that I like doing:

```
df.transform({
    "count": lambda x: [i for i in range(x)],
    "var": lambda x: x,
    "value": lambda x: x
}).explode("count").drop("count", axis=1)
```