# duplicate row values with the same row index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a data frame of samples, that duplicates (and not sampled again) if the row index is the same.

```
nums = [0.1,0.3,0.7,0.5]

country  a   b   c   d 
USA     0.3 0.1 0.5 0.7
USA     0.3 0.1 0.5 0.7
Italy   0.1 0.5 0.7 0.3
UK      0.7 0.1 0.5 0.3
Uk      0.7 0.1 0.5 0.3
UK      0.7 0.1 0.5 0.3
```

I tried:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i] = random.sample(nums)
```

but each row got a different sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of rows per country, generate samples for each of them and use the `reindex-repeat` strategy ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336762/3218693)) to expand the samples.

```
# get size
df_out = df.groupby("country").size().to_frame("size")

# generate sample for each country
df_out[["a","b","c","d"]] = df_out.apply(lambda el: random.sample(nums, k=4), axis=1).to_list()

# ***** Replace the above line with the following code *****
# ***** If it didn't work (legacy pandas version?)***
df_out = pd.concat(
    [df_out,
     pd.DataFrame([random.sample(nums, k=4) for i in range(len(df_out))],
                  columns=["a","b","c","d"],
                  index=df_out.index)
     ], axis=1)

# repeat rows based on size
df_out = df_out.reindex(df_out.index.repeat(df_out["size"])).reset_index()
```

### Output

```
print(df_out)
  country  size    a    b    c    d
0   Italy     1  0.5  0.3  0.1  0.7
1      UK     2  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.3
2      UK     2  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.3
3     USA     2  0.7  0.1  0.3  0.1
4     USA     2  0.7  0.1  0.3  0.1
5      Uk     1  0.1  0.7  0.5  0.5   <- caused by typo in given data
```

Tested on python 3.7, pandas 1.1.3, 64-bit debian 10 OS

Comment: `df_out[["a","b","c","d"]] = df_out.apply(lambda el: random.sample(nums, k=4), axis=1)`  None of [Index(["a","b","c","d"], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Comment: Please update pandas to its latest version. If this is not possible or didn't work, use the workaround instead (edited).

Comment: I got "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Comment: for  `df_out[["a"]] = df_out.apply(lambda el: random.sample(nums, k=4)` I get the list of values at "a"

Comment: May you please provide the COMPLETE steps (including the sample dataset, in a directly reproducible form, not as printed results) in your post? Also denote which version of python and pandas you are using.

Comment: `df_out = df.groupby("country").size().to_frame("size")
df_out[["vals"]] = df_out.apply(lambda el: random.sample(nums, len(nums)), axis=1)
df_out = df_out.reindex(df_out.index.repeat(df_out["size"])).reset_index()`

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index)   df2[list(df.columns)] = df_out.vals.tolist()`

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your error, but good to see that you've found a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You should use groupby function, try this:

```
df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: I got all NaN values. and my columns moved to indexes