# Repeat rows in a Polars DataFrame based on column value

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

I would like to expand the following **[Polars](https://www.pola.rs/)** dataframe by repeating rows based on values in the quantity column.

Original DataFrame:

| Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Banana | 3 |

Expected Output:

| Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |
| Apple | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |

Here is a very similar question but using Pandas instead of Polars: [Repeat rows in a pandas DataFrame based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336704/repeat-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-value)

The polars repeat function does not seem to offer the same functionality as its Pandas counterpart: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.repeat.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close.  What you were looking for was the [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) expression.

First some data.  I'm going to add an `ID` column, just to show how to apply the [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) expression to multiple columns (but exclude `Quantity`).

```py
import polars as pl

df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        'ID' : [100, 200],
        'Fruit': ["Apple", "Banana"],
        'Quantity': [2, 3],
    })
)
df
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Fruit  ┆ Quantity │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64      │
╞═════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ 100 ┆ Apple  ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana ┆ 3        │
└─────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

##### The Algorithm

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.exclude('Quantity').repeat_by('Quantity').explode()
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.lit(1).alias('Quantity')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Fruit  ┆ Quantity │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i32      │
╞═════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ 100 ┆ Apple  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100 ┆ Apple  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana ┆ 1        │
└─────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

##### How it works

The [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) expression will repeat a value in a Series by the value in another column/expression.  In this case, we want to repeat by the value in `Quantity`.

We'll also use the [`exclude`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.exclude.html) expression to apply [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) to all columns except `Quantity` (which we'll replace later).

Note that the result of [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) is a list.

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.exclude('Quantity').repeat_by('Quantity')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ ID              ┆ Fruit                          │
│ ---             ┆ ---                            │
│ list[i64]       ┆ list[str]                      │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ [100, 100]      ┆ ["Apple", "Apple"]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [200, 200, 200] ┆ ["Banana", "Banana", "Banana"] │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

Next, we use [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.explode.html), which will take each element of each list and place it on its own row.

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.exclude('Quantity').repeat_by('Quantity').explode()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Fruit  │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 100 ┆ Apple  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100 ┆ Apple  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 200 ┆ Banana │
└─────┴────────┘
```

From there, we use the [`lit`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.lit.html) expression to add `Quantity` back to the DataFrame.