# Repeat values to next rows based on column values

Tags: python-polars

I would like to update the values of columns 'e' and 'f' in such a way that, if column 'diff' has a value of either '-1' or '1' then assign the values of columns 'b' and 'c' correspondingly to column 'e' and 'f' for the current row and also to subsequent rows until the value of column 'diff' changes to '-1' or '1'.

Below is the input.

```
import polars as pl
pl.Config(tbl_rows=20)
df= pl.LazyFrame({
    "a" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "b" : [234,34,43,6,343,76,67,23,878,12],
    "c" : [934,23,1,34,2,87,23,698,65,56],
    "d" : [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('d').diff().alias('diff')).fill_null(0)

df.collect()
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ diff │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ 2   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ -1   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 34  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    │
│ 4   ┆ 343 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 0    │
│ 5   ┆ 76  ┆ 87  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    │
│ 6   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 1    │
│ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 698 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ 8   ┆ 878 ┆ 65  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ 9   ┆ 12  ┆ 56  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

What I am looking for is arriving at this output.

```
final_df = df= pl.LazyFrame({
    "a" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "b" : [234,34,43,6,343,76,67,23,878,12],
    "c" : [934,23,1,34,2,87,23,698,65,56],
    "d" : [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    "e" : [234,34,43,43,43,43,67,67,67,67],
    "f" : [934,23,1,1,1,1,23,23,23,23]
})
final_df.collect()
shape: (10, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 ┆ 1   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 │
│ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  │
│ 2   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 34  ┆ 0   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 343 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 76  ┆ 87  ┆ 0   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 6   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 698 ┆ 1   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 8   ┆ 878 ┆ 65  ┆ 1   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 9   ┆ 12  ┆ 56  ┆ 1   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

How to best achieve this with the polars API?

The following question [Repeat rows in a Polars DataFrame based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523306/repeat-rows-in-a-polars-dataframe-based-on-column-value) , unfortunately is not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could

- use [`when.then()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) to pick out the `!= 0` values
- [`.forward_fill`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.forward_fill.html#polars-expr-forward-fill) them
- use [`.fill_null`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html#polars.Expr.fill_null) to fill in the remaining `0` values at the beginning

`e3` is all that is needed - `e1` and `e2` are included just to help see each step of the process.

```py
df.with_columns(
    e1 = pl.when(pl.col("diff") != 0).then(pl.col("b")),
    e2 = pl.when(pl.col("diff") != 0).then(pl.col("b")).forward_fill(),
    e3 = pl.when(pl.col("diff") != 0).then(pl.col("b")).forward_fill().fill_null(pl.col("b"))
).collect()
```

```py
shape: (10, 8)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ diff ┆ e1   ┆ e2   ┆ e3  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 234 │
│ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 34  │
│ 2   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ -1   ┆ 43   ┆ 43   ┆ 43  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 34  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 43   ┆ 43  │
│ 4   ┆ 343 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 43   ┆ 43  │
│ 5   ┆ 76  ┆ 87  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 43   ┆ 43  │
│ 6   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ 67   ┆ 67   ┆ 67  │
│ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 698 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 67   ┆ 67  │
│ 8   ┆ 878 ┆ 65  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 67   ┆ 67  │
│ 9   ┆ 12  ┆ 56  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ 67   ┆ 67  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

You can do the same for `f` and `c`

```py
df.with_columns(
    e = pl.when(pl.col("diff") != 0).then(pl.col("b")).forward_fill().fill_null(pl.col("b")),
    f = pl.when(pl.col("diff") != 0).then(pl.col("c")).forward_fill().fill_null(pl.col("c"))
).collect()
```

```py
shape: (10, 7)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ diff ┆ e   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 234 ┆ 934 │
│ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 34  ┆ 23  │
│ 2   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ -1   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 34  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 343 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 76  ┆ 87  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 6   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 698 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 8   ┆ 878 ┆ 65  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 9   ┆ 12  ┆ 56  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @jqurious. `forward_fill` is what I was unaware of. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rle_id` to capture the effect that it should be free to change until the diff change. After that it's just a combo of `when`/`then` to set the new value to `null` when the conditions aren't meant so it can be `forward_fill`ed. To keep from having to type out the repeated old/new columns I use `string.ascii_lowercase` and a dict comprehension with unpacking. (You could do the same with `alias` notation if you prefer)

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
(
    df
    .with_columns(**{
        letters[x+3]: (
            pl.when((pl.col('diff').rle_id()==0) | (pl.col('diff')!=0))
              .then(pl.col(letters[x]))
            )
        .forward_fill()
        for x in [1,2]
    })
    .collect()
)
shape: (10, 7)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ diff ┆ e   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 234 ┆ 934 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 234 ┆ 934 │
│ 1   ┆ 34  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 34  ┆ 23  │
│ 2   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ -1   ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 34  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 4   ┆ 343 ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 76  ┆ 87  ┆ 0   ┆ 0    ┆ 43  ┆ 1   │
│ 6   ┆ 67  ┆ 23  ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 698 ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 8   ┆ 878 ┆ 65  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
│ 9   ┆ 12  ┆ 56  ┆ 1   ┆ 0    ┆ 67  ┆ 23  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. Appreciate the effort! Although I had accepted the first answer, I do like this approach of using `rle_id`  too, which I was unaware of. Usually in such scenarios, which approach is better over the other?

Comment: @Akash I don't know, it's probably data dependent