# Assign specific value from a column to specific number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to assign agent_code to specific number of rows in df2.

df1
[image: df1]

df2
[image: df2]

Thank you.

df3 (Output)
[image: Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat rows in a pandas DataFrame based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336704/repeat-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure in both DataFrames is default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, then repeat `agent_code`, convert to default index and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

s = df1['agent_code'].repeat(df1['number']).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, s], axis=1)
```