# How to create a histogram starting from data with weights

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a frequency histogram starting from some data which has been previously grouped and weighted.
See this DataFrame as an example:

```
d = {'category': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green'], 'count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3], 'average': [3.2, 5.3, 8.1, 4.3, 9.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to take into account those weights (count column) like a row which has a count > 1 should be taken into account more than once in a frequency histogram. Therefore a simple

```
df.hist('average')
```

Is not enough, because it is flattening the count data.

A possible solution is to duplicate the rows according to the count columns as follows as described here: [Duplicate row based on value in different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792263/duplicate-row-based-on-value-in-different-column)

But I find this solution to be inefficient.

Is there any other (easier) mean to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We have `repeat`

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])] # df.reindex[df.index.repeat(df['count'])]
Out[424]: 
  category  count  average
0      red      1      3.2
1    green      2      5.3
1    green      2      5.3
2     blue      3      8.1
2     blue      3      8.1
2     blue      3      8.1
3      red      1      4.3
4    green      3      9.0
4    green      3      9.0
4    green      3      9.0
```

Comment: Hi, this is cleaner than the solution I linked but the speed (and the result) are more or less the same. I was wondering if there was something better. Thank you

Comment: @espogian did you try with big data sample ?

Comment: Yes. My DataFrame has more than 7M rows

Comment: @espogian ummm...7M rows , then I usually using dask rather than pandas

Comment: Hi, I tried using Dask to accomplish this task, but I discovered that it does not support index.repeat method. Which should be the way to go with that tool?

Comment: @espogian ummm pass that to numpy repeat