# Duplicate row based on column value and modify column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This question is a follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792263/duplicate-row-based-on-value-in-different-column) other question.
For convenience I am using the same example.

```
# dictionary of transactions
d = {
    '1': ['20',  'NYC', '2'],
    '2': ['30',  'NYC', '2'],
    '3': ['5',   'NYC', '2'],
    '4': ['300', 'LA',  '2'],
    '5': ['30',  'LA',  '2'],
    '6': ['100', 'LA',  '2']
}
columns=['Price', 'City', 'Quantity']
# create dataframe and rename columns
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data=d, orient='index'
)
df.columns = columns
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
Price   City    Quantity
20       NYC         2
30       NYC         2
5        NYC         2
300      LA          2
30       LA          2
100      LA          2
```

I would like to duplicate rows based on Quantity, but I also want to modify the Quantity column so that each row represents the nth element given Price and City.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([df.loc[idx,"Price"], df.loc[idx,"City"], df.loc[idx, "Quantity"]-r-1])
                       for idx in df.index
                       for r in range(df.loc[idx,'Quantity'])]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and this is the expected result:

```
      0    1  2
0    20  NYC  0
1    30  NYC  1
2    30  NYC  0
3     5   SF  2
4     5   SF  1
5     5   SF  0
6   300   LA  0
7    30   LA  1
8    30   LA  0
9   100   SF  2
10  100   SF  1
11  100   SF  0
```

The above code works, but it looks pretty slow and un-pandas-y.
Also, now I need to rename the dataframe columns since I had to recreate the Series for each row.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the output dataframe. Please share a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with index values, get new rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False`:

```
df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Quantity'])]
df_new['Quantity'] = df_new.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)
df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_new)
    Price City  Quantity
0      20  NYC         1
1      20  NYC         0
2      30  NYC         1
3      30  NYC         0
4       5  NYC         1
5       5  NYC         0
6     300   LA         1
7     300   LA         0
8      30   LA         1
9      30   LA         0
10    100   LA         1
11    100   LA         0
```