# In Python, is there a way to progressively modify a value in a row that I am duplicating?

Tags: python, pandas

Using [Duplicate row based on value in different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792263/duplicate-row-based-on-value-in-different-column) as a framework.

As I am duplicating the rows based on the value of the Quantity column, is there a way to then modify the value of the duplicated row? As an example, for the first row, when the row is duplicated I want to change the value of the Price from 20 to 21 and if you were to duplicate the row 3 times, I would want the Price value to be 23, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Setup from the question you referred to:

```
d = {
    '1': ['20',  'NYC', '2'],
    '2': ['30',  'NYC', '2'],
    '3': ['5',   'NYC', '2'],
    '4': ['300', 'LA',  '2'],
    '5': ['30',  'LA',  '2'],
    '6': ['100', 'LA',  '2']
}

columns=['Price', 'City', 'Quantity']

# create dataframe and rename columns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data=d, orient='index'
)
df.columns = columns
```

Using the most upvoted answer from that question to duplicate the rows:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Quantity)]
```

You can increase the price by grouping by the index and using [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as follows:

```
df['Price Increase'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount() + 1

df['New Price'] = df['Price Increase'] + df['Price'].astype(float)
```

Giving the result:

```
  Price City Quantity  Price Increase  New Price
1    20  NYC        2               1       21.0
1    20  NYC        2               2       22.0
2    30  NYC        2               1       31.0
2    30  NYC        2               2       32.0
3     5  NYC        2               1        6.0
3     5  NYC        2               2        7.0
4   300   LA        2               1      301.0
4   300   LA        2               2      302.0
5    30   LA        2               1       31.0
5    30   LA        2               2       32.0
6   100   LA        2               1      101.0
6   100   LA        2               2      102.0
```

*I left some extra columns for clarity, but you could just replace price with the `New Price` and remove the additional columns, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique key like the "Product" column on my dummy DataFrame I'd do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Dummy DataFrame creation
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(4, 2)), columns=["Quantity", "Price"])
df["Product"] = np.arange(4)
df = df[["Product", "Quantity", "Price"]]
print("Original DataFrame".center(30, '-'))
print(df)

print()
# Creating repeated columns
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Quantity'])]

# Changing price on new df
df["Price"] = df.groupby("Product", group_keys=False)["Price"].apply(lambda x: x + np.arange(x.shape[0]))
df.index = np.arange(df.shape[0])
print("Changed DataFrame".center(30, '-'))
print(df)
```